# DeliverNotificationFailed Exception handling in Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-deployment, biztalk-orchestrations

Is this possible to handle `DeliveryNotificationFailure` exception on One-way File Type Send Port?

If yes, how to do this?

I followed the below steps but still not working.

1. I Kept the send shape in Scope Shape, which is handling by DeliveryFailureException Catch Block.
2. I did set the property on Send Port "Delivery Notification = Transmitted".

   For testing:
3. On Admin console, I have given the wrong file path, to get message failed. And I have give the wrong Server Instance, Either ways it is not giving the results.

Comment: Have you stepped through the Orchestration in Orchestration Debugger?  I set up the scenario described and it does catch the fault.  What are you doing inside the Catch block, do you have a terminate or suspend shape in there?   Otherwise after going through the Catch Block it will continue as it would in any other C# code.

Comment: If you do want it to continue but to make a decision based on whether it succeeded or not, then have an expression shape that sets a boolean variable (eg. bSuccess = false) in an expression shape in the catch block, then have a decide after the catch block (e.g. where the condition is  bSuccess == true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to catch the Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.DeliveryFailureException on a One-way File Type send port.
However after catching it you have to ensure that the Orchestration either Suspends, Terminates or has logic to cope after the Catch block.

[image: Orchestration]

Debug Orchestration when failed
[image: Debug Orchestration when failed]

Debug Orchestration when it succeeds
[image: Debug Orchestration when it succeeds]